# I deleted file by wrong from Finder and not able to remove its reference from xcode - xCode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

This is the error message after i deleted the localization file from Finder

[image: File Desc]

Now i am not able to remove its reference from xCode. The delete options is not available in the drop down menu:

[image: desc 2]

The file already gone, I have no choice to get it back.

I am even not able to remove the localization of LaunchScreen file at all !?!?

What can on earth remove this reference ?

Comment: Just press Backspace

Comment: @vadian did not work. If it was working, delete options would be activated

Comment: There're at least two easy options: add a blank file with the same name at the same path, delete it as you would the original; delete the whole reference to the launch screen and re-add it. A trickier solution would be to modify the project file, better not mess with it if you don't have everything backed up to a remote repository.